# CKAN missing plugin for views

Tags: plugins, view, ckan

My CKAN is showing the following messages:

- Plugin for view pdf_view could not be found
- Plugin for view recline_grid_view could not be found
- Plugin for view recline_map_view could not be found
- Plugin for view recline_graph_view could not be found
- Plugin for view geo_view could not be found
- Plugin for view geojson_view could not be found

Some strings were removed from ckan.plugins setting.

Which plugins supply these views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .ini file you should add :

ckan.plugins = recline_grid_view, recline_map_view, recline_graph_view, geo_view

ckan.views.default_views = geo_view, pdf_view, geojson_view

Note that some of these plugins requires data to be in the DataStore